# Issue with scripts not running in a basic MapReduce in Bash

Tags: bash, mapreduce

I am trying to create a basic MapReduce function in bash (I am very new at it). I have two scripts at the moment, job_master.sh and map_function.sh. I am trying to run the map function from the job master to cut from a data file, and if it doesn't exist send it to key, but if it does send it to the file of that name. Nothing is happening when I run the job_master script or the map_function script on its own with a file as an argument. It was working before I added the if statements into the map_function.

I have included both codes below if anyone is able to spot why they are not running. I tried including echo statements to test and it is not entering the loop in the job_master script, or doing anything at all in the map_function script.

MAP_FUNCTION

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r date prod remainder; do
        if [ ! -e "$prod" ];
        then
                echo $prod >> keys
        else
                echo $prod >> $prod
        fi
done
```

JOB_MASTER

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(ls | egrep 'sales_a*')

for elem in $files ; do
        ./map_function.sh $elem
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map function script is waiting for input. Look at this:

```
while IFS="," read -r date prod remainder; do
    # ...
done
```

Where will `read` get its input? It's waiting on `stdin`, but you're not passing it anything.

On the other hand, I see that you're calling the map function script like this:

```
./map_function.sh $elem
```

That is, you are passing a command line argument. But the map function script doesn't use that argument. It seems you want to redirect the content of `$elem` to the `stdin` of the script.
Write like this:

```
for elem in sales_a*; do
    ./map_function.sh < "$elem"
done
```

This also fixes some other issues you had in the script. `files=$(ls | grep 'sales_a*')` looks buggy, and it's an inappropriate way to iterate over files.